# Draw and plot Square dynamically Using HTML canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, jcanvas

I need to draw this diagram given below using html canvas.Can anyone help me.

http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-em2abcEg5nU/Ts_c3cNtfMI/AAAAAAAAABU/eQWc6SJtD0M/s1600/t31.jpg

Comment: rahulserver actually i dont have idea to plot the data inside the triangle

Comment: The data you have I guess denotes a kind of relationship between variables.So get an equation for the above triangle and put it in javascript.You can visit http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp for tutorial on HTML canvas.

Comment: What does your data look like?  You might look at d3 (data-driven-design): http://d3js.org/  Without knowing your data, it looks like you're needing a combination of a pack layout with Voronoi spacing.  Maybe even a tree layout.  Anyway, too little info provided to give you a real answer, but you have an interesting diagram there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get access to the canvas:

```
var can=document.getElementById('canvas1')
```

Now you need a context to perform the drawing functions:

```
var pen=can.getContext('2d')
```

To draw a line do the following:

```
pen.beginPath()
pen.moveTo(0,0)
pen.lineTo(50,50)
pen.closePath()
pen.strokeStyle=rgb(255,0,0)
pen.stroke()
```

To fill a path (like a triangle) do the following:

```
pen.beginPath()
pen.moveTo(0,0)
pen.lineTo(50,50)
pen.lineTo(0,50)
pen.closePath()
pen.fillStyle=rgb(255,0,0)
pen.fill()
```

Comment: gloo this works good but can you help me to plot it inside the triangle

Comment: Its kind of duval triangle (http://www.docstoc.com/docs/118499102/DGA-Duval-triangle)